# Custom sequence number generator in EF Core using Cosmos DB provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the requirement to generate a unique identifier per record of a given entity. I'm using Cosmos DB, where one collection can hold multiple document types (entities). 
Using EF Core, Cosmos DB provider, I update these collections with new/updated data, all running smoothly where EF Core generates nice GUIDs for the ID fields of my entities.

Now, because some entities are involved in communication to a customer, I need a way to generate 'friendly' unique numbers per entity. An example is an account number that follows a specific format, e.g. YYYY-###### (2019-000001 for example).

This format is defined per entity type, and the uniqueness is:
- per entity type (Which is a field in the document)
- per collection

How can I configure EF Core to use a custom number format generator when saving the entity? One approach I was thinking of, was creating a UDF in Cosmos, that generates the number based on the format, but I'm afraid that I would need to requery the document after saving, as EF Core will have no clue about the value of that field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead you can add a field with your custom generated id, add an index on it in CosmosDB and use it instead. Such a solution will be same fast and you won't have problems with EF Core.

The second option is to use a string instead of Guid and manually create an id. But I'm not sure if EF Core already supports such mapping. You can try to do this in `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`

The last option which comes to my mind is to create Guid that will fulfil your requirements and starts (or contains) required number. Like: `20190000-2629-478a-be9e-bc596f2e85c2`. But I'm not sure if it is a good idea